# PowerDNS Master/Slave AXFR chunk error: Server Failure

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, powerdns, master-slave

Short description I´m running two PowerDNS 4.2 machines on Ubuntu 20.04 with PowerDNS-Admin and  PowerDNS-recursor. Both machines use mysql backends.
The problem is, wehn ever I start a NOTIFY from the Master-Server I get this Error on the Slave:

```
No serial for 'test.local' found - zone is missing?

gmysql Connection successful. Connected to database 'pdns' on '127.0.0.1'.

Starting AXFR of 'test.local' from remote 10.250.82.10

Unable to AXFR zone 'test.local' from remote '10.250.82.10' (resolver): AXFR chunk error: Server Failure (This was the first time. Excluding zone from slave-checks until 1674800595)
```

My config on the Master looks like this:

```
allow-axfr-ips=10.250.82.11
also-notify=10.250.82.11:54
api=yes
api-key=12345678910
daemon=yes
default-soa-name=pdns1.test.local
disable-axfr=no
disable-syslog=no
guardian=yes
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
launch=
local-address=127.0.0.1
local-port=54
master=yes
slave=no
```

My config on the Slave:

```
allow-axfr-ips=10.250.82.10
allow-notify-from=10.250.82.10
api=yes
api-key=12345678910
default-soa-name=pdns2.test.local
disable-axfr=yes
disable-syslog=no
guardian=yes
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
local-address=127.0.0.1
local-port=54
master=no
slave=yes
slave-cycle-interval=60
superslave=yes
```

I also added both nameservers to the zone.
On the slave I added the master to the supermaster table in mysql backend:

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------+
| ip           | nameserver        | account |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+
| 10.250.82.10 | pdns2.test.local | admin   |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Any idears how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

id like to follow it, as i get the exact same error

2 x Linux (alma 8.7)

1 master (Autoprimary)
1 slave (autosecondary)

it creates the domain in the sql but it dosent transfer more.

I have no idea how to proceed from this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed thies error by editing the named.conf. you need th sepcify each domain with the correct master IP and port

```
nano /etc/powerdns/named.conf

zone "test.local" {
  file "/var/lib/powerdns/zones.slave.d/test.local.zone";
  type slave;
   masters {
       10.250.82.10:54;

       };
};
```

You alsow need to creat a empty file in /var/lib/powerdns/zones.slave.d withe the name from above

```
nano /var/lib/powerdns/zones.slave.d/test.local.zone
```

The problem on thise error is that PowerDNS trys to reach th master on port 53 and not 54 so you can also change the ports back to 53 and it should work fine.